# Как в строке каждый символ засунуть отдельно в массив?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Как из строки

```
NSString *TextFieldString = myTextField.text;
```

узнать количество символов и, самое главное, каждый символ записать отдельно в массив. Потом это понадобится для обработки отдельных символов.

Например для слова "test" имеем 4 символа и массив с элементами 1=t,2=e,3=s,4=t.

Answer (score 1):

Для перевода в символьный массив используйте:

```
NSString *s = @"Some string";
const char *c = [s UTF8String];
```

Либо, как вариант чуть менее емкий:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Длину строки можно узнать, как:

```
NSString *sth=@"hello";
NSMutableString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sth.length];
```

---

Данные вопросы элементарные и спокойно находятся с помощью гугла на том же [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com), например.
С помощью [такого запроса](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=objective%20c%20get%20string%20length) можно найти длину строки, а с помощью [такого запроса](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=objective%20c%20string%20to%20char%20array) - перевести строку в символьный массив.